# How to remove duplicate values in one column but keep the rows pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have dataframe as per below
Country: China, China, China, United Kingdom, United Kingdom,United Kingdom
Country code: CN, CN, CN, UK, UK, UK
Port Name: Yantian, Shekou, Quanzhou, Plymouth, Cardiff, Bird port

I want to remove the duplicates in the first two columns, only keep as:
Country: China, , , United Kingdom, ,
Country code: CN, , , UK, , 
Port Name: Yantian, Shekou, Quanzhou, Plymouth, Cardiff, Bird port

I have tried df.drop_duplicates, but it will drop the whole rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `pd.Series.duplicated` method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['China', 'CN', 'Yantian'],
        ['China', 'CN', 'Shekou'],
        ['China', 'CN', 'Quanzhou'],
        ['United Kingdom', 'UK', 'Plymouth'],
        ['United Kingdom', 'UK', 'Cardiff'],
        ['United Kingdom', 'UK', 'Bird port']
    ],
    columns=['Country', 'Country code', 'Port Name']
)

for col in ['Country', 'Country code']:
    df[col][df[col].duplicated()] = np.NaN
print(df)
```

prints

| index | Country | Country code | Port Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | China | CN | Yantian |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | Shekou |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | Quanzhou |
| 3 | United Kingdom | UK | Plymouth |
| 4 | NaN | NaN | Cardiff |
| 5 | NaN | NaN | Bird port |

Comment: Thanks Michael! It works! and i'll replace the Nan with null.