# How to get a full-page screenshot in Python using Selenium and Screenshot

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

I'm trying to get a full-length screenshot and haven't been able to make it work. Here's the code I'm using:

```
from Screenshot import Screenshot
from selenium import webdriver
import time

ob = Screenshot.Screenshot()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73298355/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-in-one-column-but-keep-the-rows-pandas"
driver.get(url)
img_url = ob.full_Screenshot(driver, save_path=r'.', image_name='example.png')
print(img_url)
driver.quit()
```

But this gives us a clipped screenshot:

[image]

So as you can see that's just what the driver window is showing, not a full-length screenshot. How can I tweak this code to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take screenshot of full page with Selenium Python with chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721734/take-screenshot-of-full-page-with-selenium-python-with-chromedriver)

Comment: It does not, unfortunately

Comment: Bear in mind that my solution - while getting most of the pages in full - can sometime return clipped pages, depening how javascript reacts to interaction with page. For this one you should use Firefox with geckodriver (and accept the respective response below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a full-page screenshot using *Selenium-Python* clients you can use the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) based [`save_full_page_screenshot()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver.save_full_page_screenshot) method as follows:

- Code:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73298355/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-in-one-column-but-keep-the-rows-pandas')
  driver.save_full_page_screenshot('fullpage_gecko_firefox.png')
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: fullpage_gecko_firefox]

---

### tl; dr

[[py] Adding full page screenshot feature for Firefox](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/7182/commits/0e355a2320c9650532d85a9c2aaf33580df14562)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can take full `<body`> screenshot of a page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python?rq=1'


browser.get(url)
required_width = browser.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
required_height = browser.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
browser.set_window_size(required_width, required_height)
t.sleep(5)
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
required_width = browser.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
required_height = browser.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
browser.set_window_size(required_width, required_height)
t.sleep(1)
body_el = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))
body_el.screenshot('full_page_screenshot.png')
print('took full screenshot!')
t.sleep(1)
browser.quit()
```

Selenium setup is for linux, but just note the imports, and the part after defining the browser. Code above is starting from a small window, then it maximizes it to fit in the full page body, then it waits a bit and computes the body size again, just to account for some scripts kicking in on user's input. Then it takes the screenshot - tested and working on a really long page.